# Looping MediaElement freezes after some minutes or halts for a second

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have a .net framwork (4.7.2) wpf application in which a video (duration: 10 to 50 seconds) should be looped all day long.

First I have implemented the way which is suggested by mirosoft (using a story board):
[How to: Repeat Media Playback (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-repeat-media-playback?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoMediaElement" Width="1920" Height="1080" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVideoUriAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <MediaElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <MediaTimeline Source="{Binding Path=VideoUri, FallbackValue=null}" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoMediaElement"
                                       RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </MediaElement.Triggers>
</MediaElement>
```

But on my test I noticed that the video feezes after 3 to 5 minutes.
I found [this](https://jcraane.blogspot.com/2012/03/continuously-looping-video-in-wpf.html) article, which descripes the same problem.
The solution: Using a 3rd party library or manage the repetition yourself.

I want to avoid using the suggested library, because it looks like it is no longer maintained. So I implemented the (very simple) solution.

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoMediaElement"
              Width="1920" Height="1080" 
              Visibility="{Binding Path=IsVideoUriAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
              Source="{Binding Path=VideoUri, FallbackValue=null}"
              LoadedBehavior="Manual"
              Loaded="Video_OnLoaded"
              MediaEnded="Video_OnMediaEnded"/>
```

```
private void Video_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VideoMediaElement.Play();
}

private void Video_OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VideoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
}
```

It seems this implementation is more reliable, but I have still one problem: the video stops for like one second when `OnMediaEnded` is fired. After that short halt the video start at the beginning.

Do you have any suggestions how to fix this short halt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void Video_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VideoMediaElement.Play();
}

private void Video_OnMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VideoMediaElement.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    VideoMediaElement.Play();
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the problem is and **how** the code helps.